# Is there a way to have Java run a file it creates?

Tags: java, file

I'm new to java, and I'm trying to get a Java program to create a .html file, put some code in it, then run it. So far I can get it to create the file and it runs correctly, but is there a way to have the Java program automatically run the .html file or must it be done manually?

Comment: What do you mean by run? Open it in a browser?

Comment: [java.awt.Desktop#open(File)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-)

Comment: can you put your code/gist that you have already tried? You mentioned run it correctly, do you mean the creation of the HTML file runs correctly?

Comment: This is what I have (minus the try/catch code):
File myObj = new File("index.html");
FileWriter videoFile = new FileWriter("index.html");
          videoFile.write("<video controls><source src='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ' type='video/mp4'></video>");
          videoFile.close();
And I wanted to have the code open teh html file it creates when the JAR executable is run. The HTML file works fine as  does the Java.

Answer (score 1):

So, it really depends on on what do you mean by "Running it", you can either:

[Create a webview](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/webview.html) and [load in the file](https://www.techgalery.com/2019/07/javafx-load-local-html-file-using.html)

Or you can make the default browser load in the file and display it like so:

```
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start c:/path/to/html/file");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // if something goes wrong
    }
```

Comment: So this code will have the default browser run the HTML file the Java created?

Comment: Yes, it will @TonyStark, but you still need to specify the path.

Comment: Mind you, it's really system-dependent. This code won't run on Linux. [You may want to look into this](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-open-a-file-using-the-default-registered-application/).